# jQuery use specific object that is dynamically named

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have been fiddling around with some more OO type JS and `jQuery;` as such it means I can create multiple instances of an object (duh). However I am having trouble using object functions and variables within `.click()` or `.on()` etc. I see the problem I know what it is; I am trying to use the local object `"this"` within a global or even specific object without having the called methods defined.
Code
    /* exported cConsole */

```
var styleDiv = "position:absolute;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:200;top:0;display:none;padding-left:6px;border-left:6px solid red;background-color:lightgrey;";
var styleButton = "position:fixed;color:white;background-color:red;bottom:0px;right:0px;";

var cConsole = function(name, parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;

    if (this.name === undefined)
        this.name = 'console';

    if (this.parent === undefined)
        this.parent = 'body';

    this.selectorDiv = 'div[name="' + this.name + '"]';
    this.selectorButton = 'button[name="' + this.name + '"]';

    this.init = function() {
        $(this.parent).after('<div style="' + styleDiv + '" name="' + this.name + '"></div>');
        $(this.parent).after('<button style="' + styleButton + '" name="' + this.name + '">Toggle ' + this.name + '</button>');
        $(this.selectorDiv).append('<button style="' + styleButton + '" name="' + this.name + '">Toggle ' + this.name + '</button>');
    };


    this.toggleIt = function(time) {
        $(this.selectorDiv).toggle(time);
    };


    this.hideIt = function(time) {
        $(this.selectorDiv).hide(time);
    };


    this.showIt = function(time) {
        $(this.selectorDiv).show(time);
    };


    $(this.selectorButton).on('click', function() {
        // I realize that 'this' is refering to the button object so this is fake.
        // I just don't know how to pass in the object.
        // I've tried setting 'var self = this' then using 'self.' as it was declared
        // before this function but still not being called correctly as its still an
        // object var.
        SOMETHING POINTING TO THE "PARENT" OBJECT.toggleIt(500);
    });
}
```

Lines: 41~50
Fiddle (repl.it): https://repl.it/GQfD/2 
Sorry if my explanation stinks..

Comment: Please copy/paste the code inside the question body, instead of pointing to the file on GitHub :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), which creates a function that has the context (`this`) predefined, as well as (some of) the argument(s) that will be passed when it gets called:

```
$(this.selectorButton).on('click', this.toggleIt.bind(this, 500));
```

Then there is a second issue: the selector buttons are not yet created when the `Console` constructor runs, so either you have to move this line of code inside the `init` method, after the buttons have been created (see updated fiddle on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GQfD/3)), or you use event delegation, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', this.selectorButton, this.toggleIt.bind(this, 500));
```

... which will only verify at the moment the event fires whether the selector button was the cause of it.

Comment: I read through the provided link however, this is not working; should I be encasing in something like doc ready?

Comment: If you have a fiddle, I could look at it, but indeed you should be sure the DOM is ready.

Comment: Indeed, the selector button does not yet exist when you attempt to assign a click handler to it. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very very much, the `bind` does the trick, and yeah didn't even think about using the doc on method! Thanks again and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.proxy()` to set the event handler with a different context:

```
$(this.selectorButton).on('click', $.proxy(this._handleClick, this));

this._handleClick = function () {
    // here this would be a reference to the object.
};
```